# Graphics.RenderMesh in update with massive loop

Tags: unity, c#, rendering, instancing

I have millions of objects that I want to render. [I found that instantiate is not suitable](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/208389/reduce-repeating-geometry-e-g-vegetation-size-and-memory-in-unity), so I'm using [Graphics.RenderMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.RenderMesh.html) which is amazingly fast and light. But here comes the problem: it takes CPU resources because we are using a loop for each object and then rendering it:

```cs
void DrwaTree(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
{
    Matrix4x4 matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(position, rotation, scale);
      
    for (int i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++)
    {
        RenderParams rp = new RenderParams(materials[i]);
        rp.shadowCastingMode = TreeShadowCasting[i];
        Graphics.RenderMesh(rp, TreeMesh, i, matrix);
    }
}
```

This function is called a million times in different scripts with different meshes. I want to find a way to make it less CPU-intensive.

One current approach I am applying is to bring different objects under a common center point (multiple center points for different objects). Then, I calculate the distance between the center point and the camera position to execute a specific loop only for objects near the camera. Is there any alternative or more appropriate approach?

Comment: Have you looked into using instanced rendering, using [DrawMeshInstanced](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced.html)? This lets you draw many copies of the same mesh with different transformation matrices in one big batched call.

Comment: Yeah we have tried that but it is limited to 1024 objects

Comment: So you render one batch of 1024, then a second batch for items 1025-2048... You can make one batch per chunk to completely skip drawing all trees in chunks that are outside the camera frustum. If you have more than a few batches this size, it's probably time to stop drawing full meshes with multiple materials for every tree anyway and switch to imposters for the more distant ones.